# Python: Combining a list with a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Firstly I have given a list with year + month as strings:

```
li1 = ["2018-01-", "2018-02-", "2018-03-"]
```

Secondly I have a list of lists with the days each month:

```
li2 = [["1", "2", "3"],["1","2"],["5","9"]]
```

**I want to achieve the following result:**

```
combined_list = ["2018-01-1", "2018-01-2", "2018-01-3", "2018-02-1", "2018-02-2", "2018-03-5", "2018-03-9"]
```

What i tried so far:

```
datum = []
count = -1
for y in l1:
    for d in li2:
        count += 1
        name = y + d[count]
        datum.append(name)
```

With the following error: "IndexError: list index out of range".
Questions:

1. Is there a possible way to solve this problem?
2. How can I reset the counter in the loop?

Comment: `for foo in bar` will put the value from the list `bar` into `foo`, not the index, so you probably want `name = y + d`, instead of `d[count]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `zip` with list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
li1 = ["2018-01-", "2018-02-", "2018-03-"]
li2 = [["1", "2", "3"],["1","2"],["5","9"]]

result = [f"{i}{k}" for i, j in zip(li1, li2) for k in j]
print(result)
# --> ['2018-01-1', '2018-01-2', '2018-01-3', '2018-02-1', '2018-02-2', '2018-03-5', '2018-03-9']
```

Comment: It works :-) But how? Can you explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li1 = ["2018-01-", "2018-02-", "2018-03-"]
li2 = [["1", "2", "3"],["1","2"],["5","9"]]

new_lst = [f"{li1_e}{li2_e2}" for li1_e in li1 for li2_e in li2 for li2_e2 in li2_e]

print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
['2018-01-1', '2018-01-2', '2018-01-3', '2018-01-1', '2018-01-2', '2018-01-5', '2018-01-9', '2018-02-1', '2018-02-2', '2018-02-3', '2018-02-1', '2018-02-2', '2018-02-5', '2018-02-9', '2018-03-1', '2018-03-2', '2018-03-3', '2018-03-1', '2018-03-2', '2018-03-5', '2018-03-9']
```